# Moderation in the community: How can we determine what is right and wrong?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I have seen a very particular situation: Usually in the SO community chat and site, the users and moderators indicate that the moderation of the site is carried out relatively by the "Community", and I put it in quotes because I feel that it is a fallacy.

I have had the impression that, for example, there is no activity in Meta and whenever there is, it is the same users who are in charge of participating... almost the same thing happens in the main site...

So what do we call those 5 or 10 people a community or the general conglomerate of users? What happens if those 5 or 10 people make a bad decision...?

If I ask a Moderator something, the answer is always to hide behind the activities of the "Community"... that is, the criteria of those 5 to 10 people...

Is it not clear to me at what moment or point or role does the CM then fulfill?

I'm just looking for an explanation.

I appreciate it if someone can weigh in here, since I don't like to fill the comments on a post when there is an explanation or discussion behind it where you interact with other or multiple users of Meta ES.

Answer (score 6):

[Start with the Stack Overflow Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and the [website's terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service).

Anything else is subject to that specific site's description of what is and isn't on-topic, usually found in [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

For gray areas or areas of uncertainty, feel encouraged to ask a question about it on that site's respective Meta site.